# How to allow "dynamic" property type on SwiftData model based on value given to it's another property

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am working on SwiftData model that a field for `details`. This field can be of various types based on what `type` model was created with. Right now I have defined possible types and structs for these, but am unable to figure out how to add such "dynamic" type to `details` field, in a way that conforms to SwiftData restrictions as well. Below is simplified implementation (areas marked with `????` are ones I am not sure about):

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

// Types
enum DetailsType: Codable {
  case Time
  case Distance
}

struct TimeDetails: Codable {
  let startTime: Date
  let endTime: Date
}

struct DistanceDetails: Codable {
  let distance: Double
}

// Model
@Model class MyModel {
  var type: DetailsType
  var details: ????
  
  init(type: DetailsType, details: ????) {
    self.type = type
    self.details = details
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use generics here so I think you need to go for a more direct solution, either one model for each detail type or use optional properties and use the type property to determine which one(s) to access-

Comment: Optionals was what I thought about as well, as using multi Model solution for my use case would require specifying different model types upstream in similar manner. If optional properties are truly the only solution, perhaps it's worth an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use generics with SwiftData models (or inheritance) so I see two approaches

First one is to add all enum values as properties and make them optional and use the `type` property to determine what properties to access.

```
@Model class MyModel {
    var type: DetailsType
    var distance: DistanceDetails?
    var time: TimeDetails?

    private init(type: DetailsType, distance: DistanceDetails? = nil, time: TimeDetails? = nil) {
        self.type = type
        self.distance = distance
        self.time = time
    }

    convenience init(distance: DistanceDetails) {
        self.init(type: .Distance, distance: distance)
    }

    convenience init(time: TimeDetails) {
        self.init(type: .Time, time: time)
    }
}
```

The second one, that I has only tested briefly but that seems to work fine with SwiftData, is to use an enum with associated values.

```
enum DetailsType: Codable {
  case Time(TimeDetails)
  case Distance(DistanceDetails)
}
```

This would clearly simplify the model so to me it looks like the preferred solution if an associated enum is acceptable and SwiftData doesn't throw any surprises on us :)

```
@Model class MyModelAssociated {
    var type: DetailsType

    init(type: DetailsType) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```